# How to substitute a content of certain javascript reference with local script for debugging?

Tags: javascript, browser, script-debugging

I need to debug jasvascript loaded by page. Loaded page are not locally placed.

Loaded js is packed. I want to substitute it with unpacked version.

Is there any tricks or browser options to make it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like Fiddler's [AutoResponder tab](http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler2/help/AutoResponder.asp) will do this for you.

You say you want to replace the JS with the "unpacked" version--if you just want to insert line breaks so you can step through in a debugger, the [Venkman](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/216/) debugger has a "Pretty Print" button which does that.

Comment: Great feature of fiddler. Thank you. I will try Venkman, it is very interesting.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are asking for after the application is already deployed somewhere so this might not be as helpful.

If your application already goes through a regular build script or process for debug or at least for release then you could do it there. You could leave the Javascript files as the un-minified/optimized scripts and when building for debug it just copies them over, but for release it runs them through your minifier/optimizer first before copying them over.

I know that jQuery uses a [Google Compiler](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/) to package the framework up, but there are other tools that just minify the code. Also it gives you a chance to run any kind of quality checking tools (such as [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/)) on your Javascript when you already have it as part of your build process.

Other then that the AutoResponder idea from above sounds promising.

Comment: Thank you. I asked about already deployed application(even third party app). +1 for quality checking tools, didn`t know about it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Charles Web Debugging Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) to map the requested JS file to a [local unpacked](http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/tools/map-local/) JS file (or any other location). It costs money, but you can use the trial for 30 minute periods.

Answer (score 0):

[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) is a really good Firefox extension that lets you manipulate the DOM and you can see the changes as they happen. This will let you insert `<script>` tags to the page.

Just Edit the `<head>` piece of html through Firebug and insert the `<script src="http://site.com/unpacked.js"></script>` somewhere in the page.

Comment: I can insert script but cannot substitute one to other.

Comment: Well, you should then save the HTML locally and change the `<script>` tag.

Comment: )) I cannot because page includes ajax-requests to the same domain. So browser will not allow make cross-domain rquests. We can consider substitute as delete+insert. But how i can delete certain script during page loading before script execution..